# what does it mean to "SSHed into the instance"

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I'm having an error; “decoder jpeg not available” with Pillow on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I googled around and saw solution but I don't quite understand this. The solution says

```
I SSHed again into the instance and reinstalled Pillow through pip (/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip), not before I has had sure libjpeg-devel was on environment before Pillow.

I ran selftest.py and it confirmed that I had support for jpeg.
```

In my understanding, I believe the solution is saying create new user and get new ssh key and uninstall pillow. Then Install libjpeg using such command

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
```

and then reinstall pillow. Then restart the app server?

Comment: "Instance", I assume, refers to a virtual machine instance.

Comment: @mhawke hmmm ok so the way I understood is right?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Instance", I assume, refers to a virtual machine instance.

It's saying to "ssh" into the VM instance - that means to login as a user there. Typically you would use a SSH client to make a secure connection to the VM, which will then provide a login shell.

Verify that `libjpeg-devel` is installed on the VM. Probably you can just run:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

Not sure if `libjpeg8-dev` will work with Pillow. You could probably install both.

To reinstall `Pillow`, do a `pip uninstall Pillow`, then `pip install Pillow`. You might have to use `sudo` if you are installing in the system wide Python installation.

Comment: oh ok, I'm not getting this error anymore but getting more errors like Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed? error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1